# Can't change keybinding in prolog-mode

Tags: key-bindings

I have the following code that is launched on Emacs startup:

```
(defun my-prolog-mode ()
  (define-key prolog-mode-map (kbd "M-a") 'pop-tag-mark))

(eval-after-load "prolog-mode" '(my-prolog-mode))
```

I expect `pop-tag-mark` function to be launched when M-a is clicked. But for some reason `M-a` is bound to another function:

```
M-a runs the command prolog-beginning-of-clause, which is an
interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘prolog.el’.
```

What is it?

Comment: Over time, you'll find you build up lots of small additions and changes to your main packages. Naming becomes important. I would just caution you against naming a function `something-mode` when it does not in fact create a mode, which is a well-established and widespread naming convention. Can I suggest `my-prolog-mode-setup` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval-after-load` expects the first argument to be the name of a file, with or without an extension. `prolog-mode` is defined in the file `"prolog.el"`, not `"prolog-mode.el"`. This should work:

```
(eval-after-load "prolog" '(my-prolog-mode))
```

Comment: Now it gives an error: `Symbol's value as variable is void: prolog-mode-map`.

Comment: Even though `prolog-mode-map` is a valid symbol. Probably, prolog mode is not loaded when `my-prolog-mode` is executed.

Comment: Ok, I find out: I had my own `~/emacs.d/prolog.el`. Renaming it to `my-prolog.el` fixed the issue.